# Same query works different

Tags: php, mysql, sql-update

I made php script that updates database:

```
<?php
include 'config.php';

$PauseID = "2";
$ProductionID = "1411979966";

$sql = "SET @max = (SELECT MAX(Id) FROM tblproductionbreaks); UPDATE tblproductionbreaks SET IDPause = '$PauseID' WHERE ProductionID = '$ProductionID' AND Id = @max;";     

mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error());

mysql_close($connect);

?>
```

While executing this script it returns error:

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that
>   corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use
>   near 'UPDATE tblproductionbreaks SET IDPause = '2' WHERE ProductionID
>   = '1411979966' A' at line 1

But if I try same update query execute by command line it works

```
SET @max = (SELECT MAX(Id) FROM tblproductionbreaks); UPDATE tblproductionbreaks SET IDPause = '2' WHERE ProductionID = '1411979966' AND Id = @max;
```

I don't understand how the same thing works differently.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can not run multiple queries as one statement with PHP. Try like this:

```
$sql = "UPDATE tblproductionbreaks SET IDPause = '$PauseID' WHERE ProductionID = '$ProductionID' ORDER BY Id DESC LIMIT 1;";
```

You don't need this variable anyway.

Comment: @Josef Fixed it. Please try again.

Comment: Thanks. I've also tried with mysqli_multi_query($sql) but it seems that doesn't work

Answer (score 0):

Its is because your PHP interpreter treats your $sql as string. Change your code to

```
$sql = "UPDATE tblproductionbreaks SET IDPause = '{$PauseID}' WHERE ProductionID = '{$ProductionID}' AND Id = (SELECT MAX(Id) FROM tblproductionbreaks)";
```

Also you can debug it by `echo $sql` and see what actually the `$sql` returning

Comment: Doesn't work. I says: You can't specify target table 'tblproductionbreaks' for update in FROM clause

Comment: why don't you get max id with a single query and pass it through a variable in your final query ?